# form element link acts as a button

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink

I have a HTML form that contains many links (around 17). I want, when a link is clicked, the form is submitted using the same ID in the link.

```
<form id="form" action="some page.php">
<a href='?value=0'>value 1</a><br />
<a href='?value=1'>value 2</a><br />
<a href='?value=2'>value 3</a><br />
<a href='?value=3'>value 4</a><br />
<a href='?value=4'>value 5</a><br />
***********************
****    CLIPPED    ****
***********************
<a href='?value=16'>value 17</a><br />
</form>
```

When a link is pressed, it send me to the same page `index.php?value=some number`. I want each link to have a certain value/id which when clicked, the form is submitted and sent to `some page.php`.

Is this possible to be done?

Comment: Why are you using a form? Are there also form elements in it?

Comment: @PeeHaa: The form will contain only the links, and I want them to act as if a `<button>` is pressed.

Comment: Why would you need a form if you aren´t going to use form elements? And what do you mean by acting like `button`s?

Comment: @PeeHaa: a link, when pressed, submits the form. I need to use the forms though. Form elements will be used later on for validations and so.

Comment: wait... what? Now it will contain form elements???

Comment: @PeeHaa: LATER ON ... NOT AT THIS STAGE OF THE PROJECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a name on your form:

```
<form id="form" name="myform" action="some page.php">
```

Add a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue">
```

Then use javascript on your link:

```
<a href="javascript:submit(17)">value 17</a>
```

or

```
<a href='#' onclick="submit(17)">value 17</a>
```

And finally, write a javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function submit(value) {
   document.myform.myvalue.value = value;
   document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

If your form contains only one field, you can also use a simple link with value:

```
 <a href="some page.php?value="17">value 17</a>
```

Comment: your answer is similar to the answer of eljunior, but you made me see a fault in the code (form name, stupid me!) also, I was forgetting the method of the form :D

Answer (score 1):

You can simply point the link to `somepage.php?value=1`.

**Edit:** Sorry, I misread! Here is the correct answer: use JavaScript to set a hidden variable and submit the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="value" />
<a onclick="this.form.value=1; this.form.submit();">value 1</a>
<a onclick="this.form.value=2; this.form.submit();">value 2</a>
```

Comment: I know this. But I'm looking for other ways to do it. I want the selections have the look of the links, but act as a `<button>`

Comment: What he gave you is exactly what you are looking for as far as I can tell.

Comment: You'd have to style the links with some CSS. Check out this article: http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

Comment: @eljunior: didn't work!! Just like you typed doesn't give a link, so I added href='#' and href='', and neither of them worked.

Comment: One way to make it to look like a real link is to use `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: @eljunior: it worked. My bad. The form didn't have a name, when set everything is done as well as the method of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use href="some page.php?value=" etc., except that a naked space is not allowed in a URL. But this means just a link—not form submission. If you want form submission, use input type=submit or button type=submit elements. The easiest way might be to input type=submit with a value parameter. However, your real problem (which cannot be guessed from the description) might have a completely different solution.

Comment: I'm using `<a href=` and want it to work as a `<button>`, so `input type=submit` is not valid in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a link but IS a button. You won't get the benefit of visited link colors but I believe this is what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/KtZPW/3/